USB Keyboard Disconnects Randomly Every Few Days
So, I'm on my PC, everything works fine for a few days, then suddenly, I hear the hardware disconnect sound, and my keyboard becomes completely unresponsive. The lights on the keyboard stay on, but none of the keys work.
I've tried unplugging and plugging the keyboard back in. The RGB lights come on, but still, nothing works. The Num Lock and Caps Lock indicators don't respond either. I’ve also switched USB ports (both front and back), but it doesn’t make any difference.
The weird part is, the keyboard works perfectly on my other PC and laptop, so I don't think the keyboard itself is the issue.
I tried

Restarting the USB Root Hub, Intel controller, and the port using USB Tree View
Uninstalling and reinstalling the keyboard drivers from Device Manager
To ensure that Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power is kept unchecked in both Power Options and Device Manager

None of this has helped. The only thing that fixes it is restarting my PC, but then the issue comes back after 3-4 days.
I've been using this keyboard with my PC for like 3 years and never had this issue before. I haven't installed or added any new devices to any ports recently.
I checked the logs on USBDeview, and it only shows the keyboard being disconnected, with nothing new. Event Viewer doesn’t log any info on devices being connected or disconnected, and enabling logging on Driver Frameworks doesn’t show anything when I connect or disconnect the keyboard.
I’m starting to think the issue might be with a USB Root Hub or the HID-compliant system controller in Device Manager, because when I first hear the disconnect sound, the keyboard is still lit up.
Another thing to note:
I have two extra buttons on my mouse assigned to the left and right arrow keys, and they also stop working when this happens. This makes me think it's something with the OS.
Any ideas on how to fix this? It's driving me crazy...
P.S.
Maybe anyone could provide a shell script to identify which device seems to get disconnected, with its time and details being logged? This could help isolate the exact thing causing the issue.
